# Can't get rid of volatile from template type argument

Tags: c++

In my code I have the following class (a bit simplified for this question, obviously):

```
template<typename T>
class MappedMemory
{
    private:
        T* localAddress;
    public:
        void* getGenericDataPointer()
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<void*>(localAddress);
        }
}
```

It doesn't work when for `T` I'll provide any `volatile` type - the compiler will point out discarding qualifiers. What can I do about it? I tried something like this:

```
void* getGenericDataPointer()
{
    auto normalAddress = const_cast<typename std::remove_cv<T*>::type>(localAddress); //To cast away volatile and const
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(normalAddress);
}
```

I also tried `std::decay` instead of `std::remove_cv`. Seems like neither works as intended:

```
error: reinterpret_cast from type ‘volatile unsigned int*’ to type ‘void*’ casts away qualifiers
             return reinterpret_cast<void*>(normalAddress);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `remove_volatile` or `remove_cv` traits to the type `T` itself, not the pointer to it.

```
auto normalAddress = const_cast<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type*>(localAddress);
```

Note that `remove_cv` removes both `const` and `volatile` qualifiers, while `remove_volatile` only removes the latter.

Comment: It works now. Thank you! Also yeah, I know `remove_cv` removes any qualifiers, that's actually my goal. But as I was working with volatile example at the moment, I typed it in the question, should have also add const to the title.

Comment: Err, this is risky. As in, potenially risks accessing an object declared volatile via an lvalue that isn't. That `void*` is an opening for that.